# Positive operator- definition

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm trying to learn functional analysis myself, and would be very happy if you could help me with some definitions I do not understand.

Let   $T:H \rightarrow  H$ be a linear operator, when $(H,\langle \cdot\rangle )$ is Hilbert space.

If I'm right, and correct me if I'm wrong, $T$ is "positive" iff: $\forall x \in H:\langle x,Tx \rangle \geq 0$.

Now, Let   $K:E \rightarrow  E$ be a linear operator, when $(E,\|\cdot\|)$ is Banach space.

Now, how can we define a positive operator for a Banach space?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: From what I've seen, an operator $T \colon X \to X^*$ is called positive if $T(x)(x)>0$ for all $x \in X$.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. By $X^*$ you mean to the dual space?

Comment: Yes. In addition to that, if you add more structure to your space like  (partial) order, then a bounded endomorphism $T \colon E \to E$ is called positive, if the set $K=\{ x \in E \colon x \geq 0\}$ (the positive cone) is invariant under $T$, that is $T[K] \subset K$.

Comment: There are lots of inequivalent notions of positivity for operators, but if you are looking for a notion that generalizes the corresponding positivity for Hilbert spaces that you mentioned, the answer is there is none.